# Как устранить конфликт jQuery и MooTools?

Tags: jquery, mootools

Есть скрипт jQuery, который подключается всегда перед `</head>` вместе с библиотекой. Мне надо использовать MooTools-библиотеку, но получается конфликт...

Пробовал использовать `jQuery.noConflict();` — не помогает.
Можно это исправить в скрипте MooTools?

Почитал про безопасный режим работы с долларом у MooTools, но так и не понял: надо все функции в безымянную функцию пихнуть или только определение классов?

Comment: Тоесть Вы после подключения библиотеки jQuery вставили jQuery.noConflict(), 
потом в самом скрипте который использует библиотеку jQuery сделали замену знака доллара $ на jQuery и все равно конфликт ?

Comment: нет, дело в том что у меня нет доступа к скрипту jquery, поэтому я хочу исправить конфликт в скриптах mootools.

Comment: А какая именно ошибка?

Comment: ошибок много из-за конфликта библиотек... там же прототипы и классы совпадают почти все.

Answer (score 1):

Надо найти и заменить редактором в одной из библиотек символ `$` на любой другой символ/символы

Comment: Или присвоить обеим библиотекам отдельные алиасы и юзать как надо.